# Bind to other element in a stackpanel without name

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm creating a `DataTemplate` in WPF, so it won't compile if I use `x:Name`. This is the relevant part of my code:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image .../>
        <Textbox Width={Binding to image?, Path=ActualWidth} />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I bind to the Image without the use of name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RelativeSource`:

```
<DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>                        
          <Image Source="{Binding Photo}"/>
          <TextBox Width="{Binding Path=Children[0].ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
       </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can't directly binding to Image but you can do that with `StackPanel` and property Children.